# Return False not working on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a log in form that I am trying to submit via AJAX. I have a similar form for registration that is working perfect; however, the return false statement isn't firing.

My log in form looks like this:

```
  <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="userSystem/userSystem.php" method="post">
    <div class="loginTable">
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="username">Username:</label></div>
          <div class="loginCell"><input type="text" name=="username" id="loginFormUser"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="password">Password:</label></div>
          <div class="loginCell"><input type="password" name="password" id="loginFormPass"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" id="loginFormSubmit"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
<section id="loginBarRegForm">
  <h1>Step Two</h1>
  <form name="regForm" id="regForm" action="usersystem/register.php" method="post">
    <div class="loginTable">
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="r_username">Username:</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="text" name="r_username" id="r_username"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_usernameFeedback"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="r_password">Password:</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="password" name="r_password" id="r_password"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_passwordFeedback"></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for"r_vpassword">Verify Password</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="password" name="r_vpassword" id="r_vpassword"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_vpasswordFeedback"></span></div>
        </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"><label for="email">Email:</label></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="text" name="r_email" id="r_email"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><span id="r_emailFeedback"></span></div>
        </div>
      <div class="loginRow">
        <div class="loginCell"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"><input type="submit" name="r_submit" value="Register" id="r_submit"></div>
        <div class="loginCell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

And the javascript that I'm trying to execute when the submit button is clicked on

```
$("#loginFormSubmit").click(function() {
  form_data = {
    username: $("#loginFormUser").val(),
    password: $("#loginFormPass").val(),
    operation: "login",
    is_ajax: 1
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "userSystem/userSystem.php",
    data: form_data,
    dataType: json,
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.success) {
        $("#loginBarLoginForm").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#userDetailsUsername").html(data.username);
        $("#userDetailsEmail").html(data.email);
        $("#userDetails").fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $("#loginbarLoginForm").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html(data.message);
        $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

So far this is about the most in depth application I've developed, but it just doesn't make sense as to why return false will work in one instance, but not another.  They are nearly identical functions except for the data.

Thank you for any help you can provide :)

EDIT: Updated Code.

```
    $("#loginFormSubmit").click(function() {
    console.log("Click Event Firing");
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#loginFormUser").val(),
        password: $("#loginFormPass").val(),
        operation: "login",
        is_ajax: 1
    };
    console.log("variables Assigned " + form_data['username'] + " " + form_data ['password']);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "userSystem/userSystem.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Ajax Working");
            if(data.success === true) {
            $("#loginBarLoginForm").hide();
                $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html("<p>You have been loged in " + data.username + "!");
                $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
            } else {
                $("#loginBarRegForm").hide();
                $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html(data.message);
                $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The code will now return a JSON respones, but the function for success is not being fired.

Comment: try using `submit()` function instead of click function.

Comment: If you are submitting your form through `Ajax` then you can simply use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` to prevent form submit

Comment: By changing the submit to a button, I'm able to get the even to fire; hwoever, the ajax is not working at all.

Comment: for some reason the dataType option was what was causing the ajax event not to fire.  Now I need to rebuild the Ajax code (because I dumbly deleted it instead of commenting it out), and we'll see what happens.

Comment: I'm reacieving a response from the server with the expected JSON informaiton; however the application isn't processing the success: function() I will update the code in my OP to what it now looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all along, I was just missing some quotes in my solution.  I needed to replace:

```
    dataType: json,
```

with:

```
    dataType: "json",
```

Once I got that, the solution came into place and now my users will be able to log in without a page refresh.  I still have a long way to go on this project, but thank you all for helping point me in the right direction.  Also I feel acomplished that I was able to find the answer on my own; however, I never would have, had it not been for the fine help and tips that I received from the SO community.  You guys are one in a million!

The final solution ended up looking like this:

```
    $("#loginFormSubmit").click(function() {
    console.log("Click Event Firing");
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#loginFormUser").val(),
        password: $("#loginFormPass").val(),
        operation: "login",
        is_ajax: 1
    };
    console.log("variables Assigned " + form_data['username'] + " " + form_data ['password']);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "userSystem/userSystem.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Ajax Working");
            console.log("data.success: " + data.success);
            console.log("data.username: " + data.username); 
            if(data.success === true) {
                console.log("data.success was true");
                $("#loginBarLoginForm").hide();
                $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html("<p>You have been loged in " + data.username + "!");
                $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#notLoggedIn").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#currentlyLoggedIn").fadeIn("slow");
                $.cookie("username", data.username, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("id", data.id, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("email", data.email, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("user_level", data.user_level, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("active", data.active, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("reg_date", data.reg_date, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $.cookie("last_login", data.last_login, {expires: 7, path: "/"});
                $("#cookieUsername").html($.cookie("username"));
                $("#cookieID").html($.cookie("id"));
                $("#cookieEmail").html($.cookie("email"));
                $("#cookieUserLevel").html($.cookie("user_level"));
                $("#cookieActive").html($.cookie("active"));
                $("#cookieRegDate").html($.cookie("reg_date"));
                $("#cookieLastLogin").html($.cookie("last_login"));
            } else {
                console.log("data.success was false");
                $("#loginBarRegForm").hide();
                $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html(data.message);
                $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`return false` inside the handler but outside the `ajax` to prevent the default action of the submit.

```
$("#loginForm").on('submit',function() {  //attach handler to form
    form_data = {...}                     //form data
    $.ajax({...});                        //fire ajax
    return false;                         //prevent default action
});
```

Comment: When I copied the code, I was in the middle of trying to move it around to get it to fire.  I have updated the code to reflect where it should appear, I am still getting the same error.  Do I have it in the wrong place still?

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 what happens? what does the console say? what does the network tab say?

Comment: The page goes to userSystem/userSystem.php

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 [here's a basic sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bNDnc/). There might be something wrong with your JS. Try validating it. Also, try putting `var` before `form_data`. It's leaking to the global without `var`.

Comment: Made the suggested changes, and also validated my JS and fixed all the errors in pointed out (a couple missing ; and some == instead of ===), but the problem still persists.  I'm going to try deleting the function and copying the one I tested that works and seeing if that makes a difference.  Will update with results.

Answer (score 0):

The return false is working as required, but the problem is that the Success method is a callback , which is called by Jquery implicitly whenever there is a successful message from the server side on ajax call, so at that time, you dont have any handle to get the value from it, so either you need to define your logic in another method and make the method call here, as its the callback ,you dont have handle to manipulate.

and yes if you want to return the `$.ajax()` call to return false, you can remove the return false statement to outside the scope of the success method.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but change the type of the input from "submit" to "button".

And, just for debugging purposes, don't dynamically assign a click event.  Change your JS to this:

```
function NamedFunction() {
  form_data = {
    username: $("#loginFormUser").val(),
    password: $("#loginFormPass").val(),
    operation: "login",
    is_ajax: 1
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "userSystem/userSystem.php",
    data: form_data,
    dataType: json,
    success: function(data) {
      if(data.success) {
        $("#loginBarLoginForm").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#userDetailsUsername").html(data.username);
        $("#userDetailsEmail").html(data.email);
        $("#userDetails").fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        $("#loginbarLoginForm").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#loginBoxResponseDiv").html(data.message);
        $("#loginBoxResponseFrame").fadeIn("slow");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Then add this to your submit button

```
onclick="NamedFunction(); return false;"
```

I'm not recommending you keep it that way, but perhaps with those 2 changes you can really track down what's happening.